# I am having issues with pointer use in C

Tags: c, list, pointers

Could someone please explain to me how this code works. I tried writing it out and wrapping my head around it, but I am still lost.

When you are setting `next->prev = prev` what is the difference in value between `next->prev` and `prev`? aren't they the same value? same question for the next line as well.

I tried writing out a `ListElement` struct to try to help understand but I am still confused. Any answer or help would be greatly appreciated, or any other references that can make me understand. I am a visual learner so if you happen to know a good visualization of this, I would appreciate it.

```
int unlink(ListElement *element)
{
    ListElement *next = element->next;
    ListElement *prev = element->prev;

    next->prev = prev;
    prev->next = next;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to draw little boxes and arrows with pencil and paper. `:)`

Comment: Can you draw a picture for yourself of the structure of the linked list? That's the key to understanding the code. If you can understand how the data is structured, the meaning of the code becomes clear.

Comment: It unlinks an element from the middle of a doubly-linked list.  It saves the pointers to the next and previous elements.  It makes sure that the `prev` pointer of the next element bypasses the current element and points to the current element's previous element; it likewise makes sure that the `next` pointer of the previous element bypasses the current element and points to current element's next element.  It doesn't free the current element.  There's no obvious reason for it to have a return type other than `void`; then it needs no return statement. As it stands, each call should be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The first two assignments define *"connections"* to the *previous*, 1, and *next*, 3, node.

```
ListElement *next = element->next;  // next connects current node to the one that follows 
ListElement *prev = element->prev;  // prev connects current node to the one that precedes
```

that is why they are called `prev` and `next`. The other two lines are *re-wiring* the `prev` and `next` nodes such that they skip the current node, i.e.
you are accessing the preceding and following nodes's members <sup>(with the same names)</sup> via the *connections* defined above:

```
next->prev = prev; // now node: 3 is connected to node: 1 
prev->next = next; // now node: 1 is connected to node: 3
```

---

Note: remember that each node has two pointers named `prev` and `next`

Comment: Thanks! this and the answer under you made it pretty easy to understand. I knew what it was doing, i just wasn't sure how. I didn't realize that `ListElement *next = element->next` was actually the next item, i thought it was just the value in next. Thanks a lot I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a linked list:

```
1->2->3
```

Pointer head points to the head of the list.
head->next points to the element 2.

```
   *
1->2->3
```

You call method unlink on it:

```
unlink(head->next);
```

By passing head->next, you passed element 2 to the function.

It will then keep pointers to the next and previous elements:

```
ListElement *next = element->next; //3
ListElement *prev = element->prev; //1
```

It will then proceed to unlink this element:

```
next->prev = prev; // now next (3) has a previous pointer to 1
prev->next = next; // now prev (1) has a next pointer to 3
```

Now 2 is unlinked and can be reused/deleted.

Comment: Thanks!. I didn't realize that `ListElement *next = element->next` was actually the next item, i thought it was just the value of the current item next. Thanks a lot I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This code removes an element from a doubly linked list.

It is done by assigning the "next" pointer of `element`'s previous element directly to `element`'s next element. Vice versa, the "prev" pointer of `element`'s next element is set to `element`'s previous element.
This has the effect that `element` is removed from the linked list.

Hope this helps.

> When you are setting next->prev = prev what is the difference in value
>   between next->prev and prev? aren't they the same value?

This only sets the pointer `next->prev`to the value of `prev`, meaning that the next element's `prev`pointer points to the same address as the variable `prev`.

Answer (score 1):

This function basically *unlinks* passed list element.

No, they don't have the same value.

- `prev->next` is the `next` pointer of the node before `element` in the list.
- `next` is defined as `element->next`, so it a pointer to the node after `element` in the list.

So, with `prev->next = next`, you basically set the `next` pointer of the node before `element` to the node after `element`.

Analog explanation for `next->prev = prev`.

This diagram from the UCLA illustrates the behavior of your function:

[image: diagram element unlinking]

Comment: It's OK to reuse images if the owner permits it — but it is a good idea to link to the original site (article containing the diagram) so that there is some chance of telling whether it is OK to do so.

Comment: The original article has disappeared. It was from [Todd Wittman](http://macs.citadel.edu/wittman/teaching.html) in his Introduction to C++ Programming. I think it is okay to use it here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's draw a diagram of the doubly linked list's elements:

```
|ITEM0        |  |ITEM1        |  |ITEM2        |
| next->ITEM1 |  | next->ITEM2 |  | next->NULL  |
| prev->NULL  |  | prev->ITEM0 |  | prev->ITEM1 |
```

Let's say we want to unlink ITEM1, we save the next element into a variable called next, that's the `*next = element->next;` part, so now `next = ITEM2`, then we save the previous: `*prev = element->prev;`, so now `prev = ITEM0`. Now, we set the previous of the next element (aka previous of ITEM2) to prev (which is ITEM0) and set the next of the previous (aka next of ITEM0) to next (which is ITEM2), so we end up with this:

```
|ITEM0        |  |ITEM1        |  |ITEM2        |
| next->ITEM2 |  | next->ITEM2 |  | next->NULL  |
| prev->NULL  |  | prev->ITEM0 |  | prev->ITEM0 |
```

Note how we moved the next pointer of ITEM1 into the next pointer of ITEM0, and the prev pointer of ITEM1 into the prev pointer of ITEM2.

At this point, we can free ITEM1 (as nothing points to it), and we have just unlinked it from the linked list!