# I am trying to write a function that removes all the odd elements from a given linked-list and also returns an adress

Tags: c, function, linked-list

of a new linked list of the odd elements removed. 
I find this task quite complicated, and I would be happy if you could help to repair or improve my code.
Here is what I've done by far:

```
typedef struct list{
      int data;
      struct  list* next;
} List;


List* removeOddValues(List** source)
{
      List* curr= source;
      List* prev;
      List* odd= NULL;

      while (curr)
      {
        if ((curr->data)%2!=0)
          {
           insertNodeToEnd(&odd, curr->data);
           prev->next = curr->next;
          }
        else
          {
           prev = curr;
           curr= curr->next;
          }
      }
     return odd;
}

List* createNewNode(int newData, List*  next)
{
       List* newNode = (List)calloc(1, sizeof(List));
       newNode->data = newData;
       newNode->next = next;

       return newNode;
}

void insertNodeToEnd(List** list, type  newData)
{
       LNode* newNode = createNewNode(newData, NULL);

    list->next= newNode;

}
```

Comment: why List** in args, instead of List* ?

Comment: `... removeOddValues(List** source) {   List* curr= source;` should have raised a compiler warning.  Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an edited version of the removeOddValues function (untested). You didn't say what the return value should be, so I just guessed it should be the new head of the list. You will need to implement a function `removeFromList` which unlinks the elements, but there are plenty of examples available (such as this one: [I am having issues with pointer use in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855253/i-am-having-issues-with-pointer-use-in-c/43855390#43855390)).

Hope that helps you as a solution.

```
List* removeOddValues(List** source)
{
    List * resultHead = NULL;

    List * currentElem = *source;
    List * nextElem    = NULL;

    while (currentElem)
    {
        // remove invalid elements (those with odd value)
        if (currentElem->data % 2 == 1)
        {
            removeFromList(currentElem);
        }
        // use the first valid element as new head of the list
        else
        {
            resultHead = resultHead ? resultHead : currentElem;    
        }

        currentElem = nextElem;
    }

    // return new head of the list
    // will be NULL if all elements were odd
    return resultHead;
}
```

Comment: `if (currentElem->data % 2 == 1)` is true for positive odd number, but not negative odd numbers.  OP's `if ((curr->data)%2!=0)` is functionally correct.

Comment: `removeFromList(currentElem);` is certainly incorrect as the effect of that function call do not change any variable in `removeOddValues()`.  `nextElem` is only set to `NULL` and never changed.  Suggest code re-write.

Comment: @volzo, it does not help me much...I want to use the functions                List* createNewNode(int newData, List*  next)   and 
void insertNodeToEnd(List** list, type  newData)

Comment: sorry, Gal, that wasn't specified in your question...
@chux you are wrong. If you no how linked lists work (see the many posts on stackoverflow), you can see that an element is removed by adjusting pointers (to next/prev). so, this will work by adjusting the pointers of the neighboring elements, and this can for sure be outside the function `removeOddValues`.

Comment: ... and @chux is right in that `List * nextElem    = NULL;` is superfluous.
without that line it should be a good, compact solution. you may of course consider using other utility functions, if that was the requirement.

Comment: @volzo  the function List* removeOddValues(List** source)  should return the adress of a new list which contains those odd nodes that are removed from the original list...

Comment: I wonder if I should use the function " void deleteNode(struct node *head, struct node *n) "  instead of  that removeOddValues function.

Comment: see here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-given-node-in-linked-list-under-given-constraints/